# Using struct with an insertion sort

Tags: c++, struct, insertion-sort

I'm having some trouble with an insertion sort, passing in data from a struct. 
It's returning the error: |98| cannot convert 'store' to 'int' in assignment.

```
struct store{
    char tag[5];
    int cost;
    long int volume;
};


void costSort(store storedEntries[], int count);
void volumeSort(store storedEntries[], int count);

int main(){

    store record[100];
    ifstream fin;
    char choice;
    int count = 0;

    fin.open("stockdata.txt");

    //file read in
    if(fin.good())
    {
        while(!fin.eof())
        {
            fin >> record[count].tag;
            fin >> record[count].cost;
            fin >> record[count].volume;
            count++;
        }
    count--;
    }


    cout << "Main Menu:" << endl;
    cout << "c: sort data by Cost\nv: sort data by trade Volume\nq: Quit\nEnter Choice: ";

    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 'C':
        case 'c': //costSort(record, count);
            break;
        case 'V':
        case 'v': volumeSort(record, count);
            break;
        case 'q':
        case 'Q': return 0;
            break;
    }
   return 0;
}

void volumeSort(store record[], int count)
{
    int p = 0, item = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<count; i++){
    cout << "test";
        item = record[i];
        p = (i - 1);
        while(p>=0 && item < record[p]){
            record[p+1] = record[p];
            p--;
        }
        record[p+1] = item;
        cout << record[i].tag << " " << record[i].volume << endl;
    }

}
```

The insertion sort is in the function void volumeSort().
Any advice would be appreciated, i haven't had any issues up until now :S

Comment: Fyi, [this is wrong: **`while(!fin.eof())`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Welcome here, please post the code where the error is detected.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, any advice on the insertion sort? 
@philant, the code where the error is detected is in the function volumeSort. line "item = record[i];"

Comment: `item = record[i]` is certainly wrong; `item` is `int`, `record[i]` is `store`. Likewise with `item < record[p]`. And `record[p+1] = item`, equally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a `int` with a `store`.

This will not work unless you overload `<` operator to compare a `int` and a `store`.

```
store record[];
int p = 0, item = 0;
//[...]
while (p >= 0 && item < record[p])
//Neither can you assign that
record[p + 1] = item;
```

Operator example:

```
bool operator<(const int &left, const store &s)
{
    //You could also do some calculation in here,
    //if you want to compare a value inside the struct
    //like this:
    return left < s.cost;
    //Please... do it in place.
    //item < record[p].cost;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "an own operator"?
I''ve tried changing the int values to store and visa versa with no luck

Comment: You could write a `operator<` function which takes a `int` and a `store` and compare both, based on one of the values in your `store` or like you wish to compare them. But you cannot compare two completely different types. This will simply not work.

Comment: @Cirrus Updated my answer with a `operator<` example.

Comment: Fwiw I see no earthly sense in writing an operator < for what is ultimately supposed to be comparing two members of two structures indexed by two indexes. Operator overloading isn't something you do because you *can*; you do it because you *should*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Of course it makes no sense here. But I have no idea what he is actually trying to achieve. Most likely test code... so at least he does know now, how he COULD overload a operator. - Updated answer...

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing non-like types with no operator provided to support the comparison (and none *needed* if this is done correctly). Currently you're comparing `int` to `store`. What you should be comparing is two `volume` members of two store objects.

A simple loop that is probably closer to what you want would be something like this:

```
// note: count is size_t, an unsigned magnitude. only used signed
//  integer types where it makes sense a negative integer will be
//  plausible input.
void volumeSort(store record[], size_t count)
{
    for(size_t i=1; i<count; ++i)
    {
        // compare current element to one below us, swapping if needed
        // and stopping as soon as we reach an equal or lesser record
        size_t j=i;
        while(j>0 && record[j].volume < record[j-1].volume)
        {
            std::swap(record[j-1], record[j]);
            --j;
        }
    }
}
```

Or something similar. Note the comparison of:

```
record[j].volume < record[j-1].volume
```

in the while condition. Apples to apples...

---

For an interesting `insertion_sort` that utilizes two wonderful features of the standard library, `std::upper_bound` and `std::rotate`, a rather dense version of the function can be created, looking something like this:

```
void insertion_sort(store record[], size_t len)
{
    for (auto it = record; it != record+len; ++it)
    {
        std::rotate(std::upper_bound(record, it, *it,
            [](const store& lhs, const store& rhs) { return lhs.volume < rhs.volume; }),
            it, std::next(it));
    }
}
```

This is considerably more efficient than it first may seem, as the search for the proper placement of the prospect element is done in O(logN) using `std::upper_bound`. Then `std::rotate` opens the hole where the element goes and it is swapped into place.

Just some food for thought. Coupled with the comparator that is going to inlined by even remedial optimization and it has a lot more punch than you may first think. Still not as kick-ass as `std::sort`, usually *highly* optimized utilizing multiple algorithms, but still good brain food.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort by volume you should take 
record[i].volume even when comparing...the types should be same when comparing values..

Similarly for other cases..